# Como usar a rota delete do Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Eu tenho a seguinte rota:

```
Route::delete('/{id}', 'PessoasController@delete');
```

Porém com o formulário seguinte não consigo acessar a rota:

```
<form action="/45" method="DELETE">
  <button type="submit">Deletar</button>
</form>
```

Não sei o que estou errando, talvez me falte conceitos, sou iniciante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeira coisa nunca, (***de maneira nenhuma***) crie um rota assim isso pode atrapalhar as demais e causar problemas, choque de rotas, *etc.*. Um exemplo básico na criação desse tipo de rota seria com `Route::post` (não precisa usar `delete` só no caso de ser um `REST Web Api`, mas, para formulário use `post` e `get` que já é o suficiente.):

***Exemplo:***

***Rota:***

```
Route::post('pessoas/delete', 'PessoasController@delete');
```

***Formulário:***

```
<form action="/pessoas/delete" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="45" />
  <button type="submit">Deletar</button>
</form>
```

---

***Exemplo minimo***

Um exemplo (*é um dica de como poderia ser*) de ***rotas*** para `Controller` pode seguir a nomenclatura do **nome do controller**, **nome do método** e **paramentos**:

```
Route::get('pessoas/create', 'PessoasController@create');  // criar registro
Route::get('pessoas/edit/{id}', 'PessoasController@edit'); // editar registro
Route::get('pessoas/view/{id}', 'PessoasController@view'); // ver registro
Route::post('pessoas/store', 'PessoasController@store');   // salvar novo registro
Route::post('pessoas/update', 'PessoasController@update'); // atualizar registro
Route::post('pessoas/delete', 'PessoasController@delete'); // excluir registro
```

onde a relação é:

- `create` utiliza `store` para **gavar registro**,
- `edit` usa `update` para **alterar registro**, e
- `view` usa  `delete` para **excluir o registro**.

Isso tudo pode ser simplificado, pode ser alterado, mas, nunca utilize rotas com um paramento e só com ele, logo de cara isso é um **erro**, atrapalha o funcionamento do site por limitar o site a não ter nomes de rotas simples.

Answer (score 3):

Os formulários HTML não suportam os métodos PUT, PATCH e DELETE.

Para contornar isso o Laravel tem uma alternativa bem útil descrita em sua documentação, [veja #Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Com isso, ficaria assim:

```
<form method="POST" action="sua-rota">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit">Deletar</button>
</form>
```

Verifique se a versão do seu Laravel permite que seja utilizado essa função `method_field`:

```
<form method="POST" action="sua-rota">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <button type="submit">Deletar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Legal, mas estou com dúvida em questão ao `csrf_field` é possível usar sem as chaves? pois estou usando angular

Comment: Eu aconselho a não usar sem chave. Mas, se realmente for necessário, você pode especificar as rotas que não passaram pela verificação CSRF. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: Eu quis dizer as chaves `{{` que entram em conflito com o angular e não geram nada

Comment: Qual template engine você está usando, Blade ou AngularJS?

Comment: Estou usando sómente Angular 1 Carlos

Comment: Você precisa passar para o AngulaJS o `csrf_field` de alguma forma. A própria documentação recomenda utilizar a `meta` tag no `header` da página, https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Obrigado vou estudar sobre me ajudou

Comment: Carlos descobri com resolver usei `<?php echo csrf_field(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

voce pode usar a rota com o  post() em formulario de metodo post ou get() em links para deletar , ai é so lincar pelo name la no input através da lib body-parser, mais facil

Answer (score -1):

**//No arquivo do formulário
(exemplo local form: resource/view/pessoas/form.blade.php)**

```
<form action="{{ route('pessoas.delete',$pessoa-> id) }}" method="GET">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
  <button type="submit">Deletar</button>
</form>
```

**//No route\web.php**

> **//Obs: o middleware use só se quiser deletar quem tiver logado**

```
Route::get('pessoas/{id}/delete','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PessoasController@delete')->middleware(['auth'])->name('pessoas.delete');
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).